# Calculate the center point between three pointsTh

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three positions, with an $X$ and $Y$ value and a value that indicates the distance to of each of the individual points (not in the same measurement). So to clarify my question:

I have three $XY$-positions and three values indicating the distance to the point (not in the same measurement). The lower the value is, the closer it is to the point.

For example: 
  Point $1(x:5,y:8,$strength$:43)$
  Point $2(x:22,y:23,$strength$:21)$
  Point $3(x:26,y:52,$strength$:132)$

I don't know if the values are actually usable/make sense as I made them up just now...

The main goal is to calculate a point in the "center" of the three points, though it can be outside

[Picture to explain it further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZHZi.png)

Comment: Does bigger or lower *strength* indicate nearness to the center?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to find a circle through three points, or what?

Comment: Do you mean the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the three points ?

Comment: I will add a picture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighted ( by reciprocal strength $s$) average for each vertex

$$ \bar{ x} = \dfrac {x_1 s_1 + x_2 s_2 +x_3 s_3}{s_1+s_2+s_3} $$

$$ \bar{ y} = \dfrac {y_1 s_1 + y_2 s_2 +y_3 s_3}{s_1+s_2+s_3} .$$

where $$ s_i= \dfrac{1}{Strength_i} $$